# Commerce editing content for products

Tags: nodes, commerce

i have a project that is based on a normal drupal, and i have added commerce modules to it,
but i can't find the module or setting that changes the way of editing the product from:

[image]

to:

[image]

can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that functionality is provided by the [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.
>
> The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.

Edit: In fact it definitely is, this is an image from the module page:

[image]